# jQuery: How to push elements with two values to an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, each

I am new to jQuery and hope someone can help me with this.

I have a large HTML table with some editable TDs where each of these TDs has the class "`editable`".

Now I need to check which of these editable TDs contains text and then **create an array with the corresponding TD's name AND text**.

So far I have the following which should be ok regarding the text but I am not really sure how I can also get the corresponding names in the array.

**My jQuery:**

```
var edited = [],
    editedName;
$('.editable').not('.default').each(function(){
    editedName = $(this).attr('name)';
    edited.push( $.trim($(this).text()) );
});
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Many thanks in advance, Tim.

Comment: Please add your html, this will help in answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should push an object:

```
var edited = [];
$('.editable').not('.default').each(function(){
    edited.push( {
        text: $.trim($(this).text()),
        name: $(this).attr('name')
    } );
});
```

You can also simplify this by using `map`:

```
var edited = $('.editable')
    .not('.default')
    .map(function(){
        return {
            text: $.trim($(this).text()),
            name: $(this).attr('name')
        };
    })
    .get()
;
```

Comment: Thanks for this as well - I like the approach with pushing the object and decided to accept this as it works best in my case. Will accept as soon as I can !

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question on this: I just updated my code as per your first suggestion and used console.log(edited) after the loop to see the result but this only returns the word "Object" for each edited item instead of the actual objects. Any thought what could cause this ? - This applies to the map approach as well.

Comment: @WhistleBlower, edited is an object. So, you should try something like this: console.log(edited[0].name);

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh: Thanks a lot - this fixed it. I really appreciate your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
    var edited = [],

    $('.editable').not('.default').each(function(){
        var editedName = $(this).attr('name)';
        var editedText = $.trim($(this).text());

        var editedItem = {};
        editedItem.Name = editedName;
        editedItem.Text = editedText;

        edited.push(editedItem);
    });
```

And then, if you want to read the values back from edited array, you can do like this:

```
$.each(edited, function(i, editedItem){    
      var $thisEditedItemName = editedItem.Name;
      var $thisEditedItemText = editedItem.Text;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this - this works perfect ! - alexander's approach seems a bit more easy for me in this case so I decided to accept that answer but yours still helped me a lot !

Comment: Just wanted to add here that this works really great too - the other approach just seemed a bit shorter.

Comment: @WhistleBlower, i agree with you.